# Extract the data from string through R

Tags: r, stringr

I have one data frame which has category one of the column. Data in category column mentioned below :

```
Application Platforms|Real Time|Social Network Media
Apps|Games|Mobile
Curated Web
Software
Games
Biotechnology
Analytics
Mobile
E-Commerce
Entertainment|Games|Software
Networking|Real Estate|Web Hosting
```

The category list is a list of multiple sub-sectors separated by a pipe (vertical bar |). I want to extract the primary sector which is the first string before the vertical bar("|").

That means I want the output should be,

```
Application Platforms
Apps
Curated Web
Software
Games
Biotechnology
Analytics
Mobile
E-Commerce
Entertainment
Networking
```

Please help me how can I do this through using any function, I have tried using stringr package functions.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sub` here:

```
df$category <- sub("^([^|]+).*", "\\1", df$category)
```

Here is another variation which doesn't use a capture group:

```
df$category <- sub("\\|.*", "", df$category)
```

### Demo

Comment: `sub` works because it will extract only the first match.

Answer (score 2):

Using `strsplit`:

```
category1 <- strsplit(df$category, "|", fixed = TRUE)
df$category <- sapply(category1, `[[`, 1)     # or, purrr::map_chr(category1, 1)
```

This solution makes your intention a bit clearer than using `sub`, I think. Then again, it requires an extra line.

Answer (score 1):

Or using `stringr`...

```
str_match("Application Platforms|Real Time|Social Network Media",
       "^(.+?)[|$]")[,2] #match start of string up to first | or end or string

[1] "Application Platforms"
```

or...

```
str_replace("Application Platforms|Real Time|Social Network Media",
       "\\|.+$","") #replace | and any subsequent characters with ""

[1] "Application Platforms"
```

or...

```
str_extract("Application Platforms|Real Time|Social Network Media",
       "[^|]+") #extract first sequence of characters that are not a |

[1] "Application Platforms"
```

or...

```
str_split_fixed("Application Platforms|Real Time|Social Network Media",
       "\\|",2)[,1] #split at first | and take the first section

[1] "Application Platforms"
```